# Automatic generation of R class in Android

Tags: android

Actually, in Android when a resource (Layout, strings ...) is modified the R class is automatically generated.
How this has been done technically?
I have an XML file and I need to do the same to generate some classes. Do you have any idea?

Comment: look that R is stands for Resource file in that your all the variable and all things are mapped to some memory location. you can't create that and you can't edit that file. one thing you can do is rebuild your project it will recreate R.java and all references.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer to my question. I need to understand how this was done technically because I need to do the same for other files.